# Отличие между значением указателя и значением, на которое ссылается указатель

Tags: c

Никак не могу понять, может кото-то подскажет?
Написать программу на Си, демонстрирующую отличие между значением указателя и значением, на которое ссылается указатель. Для этого объявить переменную-указатель, зарезервировать под значение динамическую память, присвоить по адресу, содержащемуся в указателе, какое-либо значение. Напечатать значение указателя, размер памяти, занимаемой указателем, значение указателя со снятой ссылкой и размер памяти, занимаемой этим значением. Программу выполнить с использованием моделей памяти small и large.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: пример-аналогия: значение указателя: ул. Широкая, д.2, кв. 15. Значение, на которое ссылается указатель: Арбузов Николай (который там живет).

Comment: Если не рассматривать указатель на указатель и тд и тп, то в тривиальном виде указатель в качестве значения принимает адрес переменной, как та (переменная/адрес на которую ссылается указатель) в свою очередь  ссылается на значение определенного типа. Тип данных указателя должен совпадать с типом значения на который он ссылается.

Comment: Надо написать программу на Си, а я не могу разобраться как.

Comment: Ну чтобы написать программу, надо сначала почитать какой-нибудь учебник.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Перевожу комментарий в ответ:

Думаю аналогия понятна. Также можно сделать для других типов (short, long и тд), только вместо **int** нужно написать соответствующий тип, а также спецификаторы (%hd - short, %ld - long, %lld - long long).

Для полного понимания, рекомендую прочитать книгу - [Язык программирования Си. Брайан Керниган, Деннис Ритчи.](https://www.r-5.org/files/books/computers/languages/c/kr/Brian_Kernighan_Dennis_Ritchie-The_C_Programming_Language-RU.pdf)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



int main()
{
    // Русская кодировка
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("cls");

    // Выделяем память для указателя
    int* pVar = NULL;
    pVar = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    // Проверка на NULL (сейчас не обязательно, но рекомендуется так делать)
    if (pVar != NULL)
    {
        *pVar = 100;

        printf("Адресс указателя: %p\n", (void*)&pVar);
        printf("Размер указателя (байт): %zd\n", sizeof(pVar));
        printf("Значение указателя: %p\n", (void*)pVar);
        printf("Разыменованное значение указателя: %d\n", *pVar);
        printf("Размер разыменованного значения указателя (байт): %zd\n", sizeof(*pVar));
    }


    // Очистка ранее выделенной памяти
    free(pVar);
    pVar = NULL;


    return  0;

}
```

Comment: UB из-за несоответствия спецификатора преобразования и типа фактически передаваемого в функцию `printf` аргумента. `%p` требует `void*`, а передаются `int**` и  `int*`; `%d` требует `int`, а передаётся `size_t`.

Comment: @wololo %p -  спецификатор преобразования, отображающий машинный адрес в формате, совместимом с адресацией, которая используется компьютером. А для оператора sizeof можно использовать спецификатор %d (тк size_t относится к ряду целочисленных типов). P.S.: Суть Вашего комментария мне ясна, но зачем усложнять данный пример? Человеку нужно для начала освоить эту тему на простых примерах, а потом уже углубляться во все тонкости спецификаторов и тд и тп.

Comment: `%p - спецификатор преобразования, отображающий...` — это не отменяет того факта, что [спецификатор `%p` требует аргумент типа `void*`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24867814). `А для оператора sizeof можно использовать спецификатор %d` Нельзя, т.к. такая конструкция вызывает неопределённое поведение. `зачем усложнять данный пример?` Если использование явного приведения типа `(void*)` и спецификатора `%zu` для `size_t` — это «слишком сложно», то как человеку бороться с [предупреждениями компилятора](https://rextester.com/NPSC13025)?